vscode times out at "waiting for debugger connection" despite that I can manually start gdb and connect to the server
Trying to setup vscode to debug a stm32 with the STLINK-V3 debugger probe.
The server starts correctly and can communicate with the probe. I can manually start gdb ( the same gdb vscode is configured to use), connect to the gdb server launched by vscode and debug just fine. But vscode times out at "waiting for debugger connection". So presumably the gdb instance started by vscode can't connect to the gdb server. What can be the cause of this? It's not port mismatch. launch config below
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "${config:STM32VSCodeExtension.cubeCLT.path}/GNU-tools-for-STM32/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe",
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:3333",
      "debugServerPath": "${config:STM32VSCodeExtension.cubeCLT.path}/STLink-gdb-server/bin/ST-LINK_gdbserver.exe",
      "debugServerArgs": "--stm32cubeprogrammer-path ${config:STM32VSCodeExtension.cubeCLT.path}/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin --swd --port-number 3333",
      "serverStarted": "Waiting for connection on port .*\\.\\.\\.",
      "stopAtConnect": true,
      "postRemoteConnectCommands": [
        {
          "text": "load ${command:cmake.buildDirectory}/${command:cmake.launchTargetFilename}"
        }
      ],
      "logging": {
        "engineLogging": true
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "Build",
      "svdPath": "${config:STM32VSCodeExtension.cubeCLT.path}/STMicroelectronics_CMSIS_SVD/STM32H735.svd"
    }
  ]
}


